# RecursiveIteratorIterator last child

Tags: php, loops, iterator, spl

I iterate through a multidimensional array with RecursiveIteratorIterator and would like to be able to know if the current element is the last child of it's depth. I thought about this:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($array,
  RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);    
foreach ($iterator as $val) {
  $next = clone $iterator;
  $next->next();
  $lastChild = ($next->getDepth() < $iterator->getDepth());
}
```

But the RecursiveIteratorIterator says it's not cloneable.

Comment: @Bobby: Why is the spl tag meaningless? This is definitely an spl question.

Comment: @Dennis Haarbrink: There are only 42 questions on SO tagged with `[SPL]`, so I'm not sure if it adds something of value to the question. I'm also not sure if this wouldn't be synonymous with `[php]` itself, since I also don't tag C# questions with `[mscoree]` or `[System-Data]`. But that might be worth a discussion on Meta.

Comment: I tagged "php loops iterator last-child", don't understand your comments.

Comment: @Bobby: I figure if the tag exists and it is active (and of course descriptive of the problem), you should use it. Whether it is a valuable tag is debatable of course.

Comment: @sod: Check the rev history of the question. I added the spl-tag, but it was removed by Bobby.

Comment: @sod: And I removed the `[last-child]` tag. @Dennis Haarbrink: I'll re-add it (because I'm in doubt) and ask on Meta. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: How would you handle an item at depth=2, next is an item at depth=3, next is an item at depth=1? Still valid as 'lost of its depth', but the next depth is higher rather then lower...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The phrase "last child of its depth" is not particularly clear. Could you elaborate on precisely what you mean; the intended use for this?

If you mean, quite simply, that the depth will change after the current element, then the `(Recursive)CachingIterator` has a handy `hasNext` method to determine whether the iterator has any further items. To give a watered-down example similar to that in the question:

```
$array  = array(
    range(1,6),
    range(7,8),
    'foo' => range(1,3),
    'bar' => range(4,5),
);

$rit = new RecursiveArrayIterator($array);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveCachingIterator($rit),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);
foreach ($iterator as $val) {
    $lastChild = !$iterator->hasNext();
    if ($lastChild) {
        echo "$val is the last child!\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
6 is the last child!
8 is the last child!
3 is the last child!
5 is the last child!
```

Comment: I should really get around to documenting the caching iterators. (Any volunteers would be welcome.) I'm sure that the lack of docs is not making life easier for you guys! :)

Comment: almost exactly six years later and it still hasn't gotten any easier...

Comment: In PHP 7.2 that code crashes with "Array to string conversion". What has changed RecursiveCachingIterator?

Comment: @temuri it won't *crash* (by default), but will issue an `E_NOTICE` as of PHP 5.4 because the caching iterator tries to cast the arrays to strings during iteration.  This is because the default for the `$flags` parameter to the `RecursiveCachingIterator` constructor is `RecursiveCachingIterator::CALL_TOSTRING`.  To not have it do that, you can pass `0` or `RecursiveCachingIterator:: TOSTRING_USE_KEY` or `RecursiveCachingIterator:: TOSTRING_USE_CURRENT` for the `$flags` parameter.